# Ошибка при больших входных данных

Tags: c, динамические-массивы

Имеется программа, которая выводит простые числа (Решето Эратосфена) до некоторого `n`. Проблема в том, что при достаточно малых `n` программа работает, как ей и полагается, но вот, допустим, при `n=1000000` выползает run-time error.
Не могу понять в чём тут дело

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
    freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
    long n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    bool *a=(bool *)malloc(sizeof(bool)*n);
    for(long i=0;i<=n;i++)
        a[i]=true;
    a[0]=false;
    a[1]=false;
    for(long i=2;i<=n;i++)
        if(a[i])
            if(i*i<=n)
                for(long j=i*i;j<=n;j+=i)
                    a[j]=false;
    for(long i=0;i<=n;i++)
        if(a[i])
            printf("%d ",i);
    free(a);
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Начнем с того, что вот тут

```
bool *a=(bool *)malloc(sizeof(bool)*n);
for(long i=0;i<=n;i++)
    a[i]=true;
```

Вы уже выходите за границы массива... `a[n]` - за пределами запрошенной памяти. Дальше даже не смотрел...

Еще одна ошибка - вот тут:

```
    if(i*i<=n)
```

При больших значениях `i` вы получаете переполнение, `i*i` оказывается меньше нуля - со всеми вытекающими...

Вот ваш код - исправленный до рабочего:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
    freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
    long n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    bool *a=(bool *)malloc(sizeof(bool)*(n+1));

    for(long i = 0; i <= n; i++) a[i] = true;

    a[0]=false;
    a[1]=false;

    for(long i = 2; i*i <= n; i++)
    {
        if(!a[i]) continue;

        for(long j = i+i; j <= n; j+=i )
            a[j]=false;
    }
    for(long i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        if(a[i])
            printf("%d ",i);
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо вам, но есть ещё один вопрос, когда мы выходим за размер типа данных, у нас же просто число обрезается, а от куда там может появиться отрицательное число?

Comment: Вообще-то это отдано на откуп компилятору. Подавляющее большинство (а попросту все, с которыми я сталкивался :)) просто выполняют в таком случае арифметику как с беззнаковыми значениями, с приведением потом к знаковому типу - где старший бит - знаковый. Вот и выходит отрицательное значение. `0x7FFFFFFF + 1 = 0x80000000`, в десятичном - `2147483647  + 1 = -2147483648`...

Comment: И все равно `i * i` осталось. Для 64-разрядов при 3037000500 наступит переполнение (-9223372036709301616)

Comment: @avp Если вы о моем коде - то не наступит, так как цикл завершится по достижении `i*i==n`.

Comment: Формально, конечно же,  при `n > 9223372030926249001`  (у меня 2.5 sec на простой цикл) он не завершится. Лучше найти `sqrt(n)` и сравнивать `i` с ним.

Comment: @avp Достаточно добавить на всякий невероятный случай в условие цикла `i*i > 0`.

Comment: В принципе да, но это не решит задачу (перебор чисел  <= sqrt(n)).

Comment: @avp Да почему же? Если строго равно корню из n, условие будет выполнено. Если превысит или, превысив, уйдет в минуса - цикл завершится.

Comment: Согласен, sqrt(LONG_MAX) на 1 меньше, чем `i * i`, вызывающее переполнение. Но, согласитесь, эффективней один раз вычислить sqrt, чем умножение на каждом шаге цикла.

Comment: @avp Ну, разве что написать свою функцию целочисленного корня (кстати, очень несложно...) - до такой степени не хочется притягивать плавающую точку, вы бы только знали... :)

Comment: Ну, да -lm прописывать всегда рука не поднимается.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55641/discussion-between-avp-and-harry).